# how to create multiple endpoint by coding?

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0

Endpoint is created in app.config as given below, but how to create multiple endpoints with different addresses?

**app.config**:

```
 <service name="PokerService.PlayerService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorPlayer">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5054" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="player" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PlayerBinding" contract="PokerService.IPlayerService" />
    <endpoint address="player/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="ServiceBehaviorPlayer" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

but how can i generate like this `Tcp//localhost/player/1 ( 1-1000)`.Anyone have any idea?

Comment: I dont fully understand your question. What is it that does not work?

Comment: how i generate endpoint like "Tcp//localhost/player/1" to "Tcp//localhost/player/1000" by coding and also update in app.config?

Comment: you need a 1000 endpoints?!

Comment: i need dynamically generate endpoints address starting from 1 to atleast 10.

Comment: I assume you design a service for multiple players? Therefore you will not need one endpoint for each player. This would be a bad design. You should implement the player management in your service and either use a single instance service or one instance for each connection. use the according service class attributes to achieve this.

Comment: i made management service and you said right. i use single instance                             System.Threading.ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);         but how i create multiple endpoint for multiple player?
            binaryHelper.Initialize(server, game, port, waitHandle);
            server.Initialize();

Comment: Please explain: how should the player know which his number is, to address your numerated endpoint? This only makes sense to me, if your client connects to some kind of load balancer service at first, to assign an number to a new client.

Answer (score 2):

This will create 1000 endpoints on a host.

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(PokerService.PlayerService));
 for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
 {
   host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(PokerService.IPlayerService), 
                                  new NetTcpBinding(),
                                  @"net.tcp://localhost:5054/player/"+i);
 }
 host.Open();
```

**Edit**

I agree with @JanW - that this approch is ludacris- and as @JanW sais, you should let the ServiceHost deal with concurrency, by configure the [ServiceBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.aspx) on your implementation.

However, to get a complete list of hosted endpoints do this:

```
foreach (var e in host.Description.Endpoints)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Address);
}
```

Comment: i need to create multiple instances for games on one sever.that's way i need multiple endpoint like "net.tcp://localhost:5054/player/1 " to "net.tcp://localhost:5054/player/10".now i want know where that new endpoints save and how to get back?